# iOS releasing Reference iPhoneContactList with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

in my application I am fetching contact list from the device ,
it is all goes as planned until I reach the release line.

the application compiles as needed , but in runtime it is just stops , pointing me to the release line and telling in green lighted text bad access.

here is my code:
The function called with `GCD` on my own queue (since it is a big process I making it in background , I am not sure if I have to use `@autoreleasepool`

I ran product->analyze and here something in this function I adding in comments.

```
-(void)getContacts
{
@autoreleasepool {
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(iPhoneAddressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
    {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}
if (accessGranted)
{
    CFErrorRef error = nil;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error); // indirection
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSMutableArray* EmailArrayPerPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//value stored to EMailArrayPerPerson during its initialization is never read
    NSMutableArray* PhoneArrayPerPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//value stored to PhoneArrayPerPerson during its initialization is never read
    for (int i = 0; i < ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); i++)//potential leak of an object stored in to contact
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *ContactsDetails = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        NSString *contact = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));
        if([contact length] <=0)
            continue;
        ContactsDetails = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [ContactsDetails setObject:contact forKey:@"CName"];
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        EmailArrayPerPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSLog(@"dictionary is:%@",[ContactsDetails objectForKey:@"CName"]);
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++)
        {
            NSString* email = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j));
            [EmailArrayPerPerson addObject:email];
        }
        [ContactsDetails  setObject:EmailArrayPerPerson forKey:@"CEMails"];//potential leak in emails
        ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        PhoneArrayPerPerson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); j++)
        {
            NSString* phone = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, j));
            [PhoneArrayPerPerson addObject:phone];
        }
         [ContactsDetails setObject:PhoneArrayPerPerson forKey:@"CPhones"];
         [Contacts addObject:ContactsDetails];
          CFRelease(ref);//incorect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller.
          CFRelease(multi);
    }
    CFRelease(allPeople);//Potential leak of an object stored in to addressBook
   // CFRelease(addressBook);// *strange issue with bad access is here* 
}
else
{
    CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);
    return;
}
}
}
```

I know it is big function , but I think I had to add it as is to make everything clear.
I am quite new to `iOS SDK` so please can you explain me what is just happening with the bad access there ?

I am not sure but I think `addressBook` is redundant allocation since I already allocated `iPhoneAddressBook` I am not sure .

(I am also not sure if i have to release it (since I am useing `ARC` ,but `ARC` shouldnt release `crefs` for me)).

Comment: Did you try Product->Analyze in Xcode to find possible memory management problems?

Comment: @MartinR No , as I said I am new to the Xcode and iOS 
I will try it now , thanks for suggestion!
I meant I didnt know what is it , and I just googled for stuff like that .

Comment: Analyze found 23 issues Most of them is `dead store` , some other issues were found in this particular function. updating my question with analyze result

Comment: Can I toggle of the dead store marking in analyzer?

Comment: Go to the Xcode Build settings, section "Static Analyzer - Generic Issues", and set "Dead Stores" to NO :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem seems to be here:

```
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
// ...
CFRelease(ref);  // <-- WRONG
```

`CFArrayGetValueAtIndex()` does not have "Create" or "Copy" in its name, therefore you
do not "own" the returned object and must not release it.
See ["Ownership Policy"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) in the " Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation" for more information.

To solve the potential leak of `contact`, replace

```
NSString *contact = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));
```

by

```
NSString *contact = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(ref));
```

`ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` *has* "Copy" in its name, so you own the returned object.
`__brigde_transfer` "transfers" the ownership to ARC, so that the object is
released when `contact` goes out of scope.

Comment: Because I getting its value and not the reference. Yeah it makes sense , I will fix it and then run the code with releasing the addressBook again

Comment: Yes , Worked as a Charm Thank you very much :) can you also watch in the line above `addressBook` release it says potential leak of object stored in `addressBook` ?

Comment: Oh thank you very much, about the dead store I see it is more like a Warning message I don't see I have to do something with it right ?

Comment: @user2957713: I copied your code and do not get an Analyzer warning on `CFRelease(allPeople)`. Yes, the dead stores are warnings only but do no harm. - Note that you can click on the small blue icon of each Analyzer warning to get a detailed description about the problem. (Sometimes hard to read, but often very useful!)

Comment: I am sorry to abuse your helping , but here is something I don't get
` [ContactsDetails  setObject:EmailArrayPerPerson forKey:@"CEMails"];//potential leak in emails `

Comment: I clicked:-> it drawing curves but on 13inch display is really unreadable :( (still thanks for advice )

Comment: @user2957713: You have to add `CFRelease(emails);` because you "own" the object returned by `ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(...)`. - The idea should be clear now?

Comment: Yes, I should release everything I own , and to ignore the things I don't own -> Thank you very very much !